# codeigniter model not loading into controller, but no errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I am having trouble with a models in Codeigniter. I setup a model called *Usermodel* in /models/usermodel.php. and when I attempt to load it is stops the scrip and anything after it.

When I purposely entered a wrong name in the ->load->model area CI throws up an error, saying it can't be found (like expected) When everything is correct nothing is loaded.

I for the life of me can't see what is going wrong. Any idea? Thanks, Tim

**User model**

```
class Usermodel {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function displayUser()
    {
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

**And the class is**

```
class Page extends Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();                  
    }

    function index()
    {

        echo "<h1>Test</h1>";
        $this->load->model('usermodel');
        $this->usermodel->displayUser();
    echo "<p>Model loaded</p>";

    }

}
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? This might be preaching to the converted, but the __construct only works in >PHP5. Anything below and you'd want to call the constructor the same name as the class.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your version of CI, you need to extend the base Model, right now you are just making a new blank Class called `Usermodel`

example

```
class Usermodel extends CI_Model {   //<-- Note "extends CI_model"

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

This syntax is for Codeigniter 2.0

[Documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy)

Answer (score 3):

You missed to extend the class to 'Model' CI class:

```
class Usermodel extends Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::Model();
    }

    function displayUser()
    {
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Incorrect, if you are using 1.7.x you need to have your constructor call `parent::Model()`, and if you are using 2.0 the PHP5 constructor is allowed, but you have to extend `CI_Model`

Comment: Arh bugger! i took that off while messing about with it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to load in the __construct first.

**Note:** the path isn't a url, it is a directory path.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('path/to/your/usermodel');
}
```

Then in you index function is the same than you did.

```
function index()
{
    echo "<h1>Test</h1>";
    $this->load->model('usermodel');
    $this->usermodel->displayUser();
    echo "<p>Model loaded</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a naming convention issue for models. If you are using codeigniter 3.x then see the documentation.

- `class Model_student extends CI_Model`
- save model as `Model_student`, Then load it as
- `$this->load->model(Model_student);`

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

I hope this will help you.